# Exponentiation by squaring (getting the number of multiplications)

Tags: java, math

I'm doing a homework were I have to do two things using [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). One is to get the number of multiplications and the other is getting the actual result.

Here are some example:

```
2
11
```

Should output

```
2048
5
```

because `2^11 = 2(2((2)²)²)²`

I'm doing this without recursion and I'm getting the result right but the number of multiplications is wrong. If I input `2^6` I'm getting `3` multiplications and that is OK but If I input `2^8` I'm getting `4` multiplications and this is wrong.

Can you point me to what I'm doing wrong in getting the correct multiplications involved?

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x, result = 1;
    int n, multiplications = 0;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    Scanner readLine = new Scanner(System.in);

    x = readLine.nextDouble();
    n = readLine.nextInt();

    if (n == 1) {
        multiplications++;
        System.out.print(df.format(x) + "\n" + multiplications + "\n");
    } else if (n == 2) {
        x *= x;
        multiplications++;
        System.out.print(df.format(x) + "\n" + multiplications + "\n");
    } else {
        while (n > 0) {
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                multiplications++;
            } else {
                multiplications++;
                result *= x;
                n--;
            }
            x *= x;
            n /= 2;
        }
        System.out.print(df.format(result) + "\n" + multiplications + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the multiplication part. How did you got that output? and how you can't get any other output, based on order and position of brackets?

Comment: See the link I posted on the exponentiation by squaring. The multiplication part is not working as expected so this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `n % 2 == 0`, you do not multiply; you just square. so leave the `multiplications++` away.

Then for 2^8 you get:

```
n  |  n % 2  |  multiplications
----------------------
8  |  0      |  0
4  |  0      |  0
2  |  0      |  0
1  |  1      |  1
```

And 1 multiplication should be correct. Since `2^8 = (((1² * 2)²)²)²`

If you want to count squaring as a multiplication, you should do

```
... else
    multiplications = multiplications + 2
```

And afterwards subtract 2 for the initial squaring and multiplication.

So overall:

```
while (n > 0) {       
    if(n % 2 == 1) {
        multiplications++;
        result *= x;
        n--;
    }
    multiplications++;
    x *= x; // shouldn't that be result *= result?
    n /= 2;
}
multiplications -= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but every `2²` counts as one multiplications. So `x^8` has `3` multiplications since `x^8 = ((2²)²)²` and `x^11 = 2(2((2)²)²)²` so `5` multiplications

Comment: I followed your remark if I want to count squaring as multiplications and now I believe it is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you should look at is the **binary representation** of the number. The binary representation of 11 is 1011. Read from left to right. For each new binary digit, square the result. Then for each 1, also multiply by the factor.

For 2 ^ 11 you do:

First digit is a one, so 2.

Next one is a zero, so only square the 2. 4.

Next one is a one, so square the 4 and multiply by 2. 4 squared is 16. Times 2 is 32.

Next one is a one, so square and multiply. 32 squared is 1024. Times two is 2048.