# non-recursive algorithm of a^b with time complexity of log(b)

Tags: math, time-complexity

There is a project in which I should achieve the algorithm of power(a,b) which produces a^b, and the algorithm should have complexity of log(b) (b is the second input number in the function) and also the algorithm should be non-recursive. can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried solving it by yourself? If yes, try posting your solution so we can see what is the problem. If no, try it before, might me more easy than you think.

Comment: sure i have tried but i haven't achieve anything :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exponential multiplication algorithm that runs in O(n) time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534100/exponential-multiplication-algorithm-that-runs-in-on-time)

Comment: Other previous discussions of this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920118/3088138, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250468/3088138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to construct the multiplications needed with squares and multiplies

Let's start with a concrete example: 7^13

13 is 1101 in binary

So `7*((7^2)^2*((7^2)^2)^2)=7^(1+4+8)=7^13`

Algorithmically:

1. Let x=a, res=1
2. Go over b's bits from minor to major

   1. if current bit is 1 than, res=res*x
   2. x=x*x

Time complexity is the same as the number of b's bits, which is log(b)

Comment: Anytime.
you can read more about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring